# How can copying an entire list and appending an element be more efficient than just appending it?

Tags: performance, append, immutability

Some [claim](http://himera.herokuapp.com/synonym.html) that appending to immutable lists is more efficient. Is this true? How?

Comment: Can't see no claims at the link.

Comment: Search for: "*efficient dynamic binding*"

Comment: I actually have no clue what you are talking about, but if lists are implemented in an immutable and singly-linked manner, then extracting and reusing any suffix of the list and prepending it with a new head is a trivial operation (just add a new cell with a pointer to the tail, no copying involved). See [what Wikipedia has to say on tail-sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail-sharing#Singly_linked_linear_lists_vs._other_lists) for more information.

Comment: @NiklasB. This depends on the implementation of the immutable list.  Certainly a list in Scheme behaves this way, but a Java array doesn't, for instance.

Comment: @dimo: I was explicitly talking about an immutable, singly-linked list, which a Java array is clearly not (it's neither immutable nor a linked list, let alone singly-linked).

Comment: The question is to immutable lists as a whole, I wasn't disagreeing with you, merely pointing out that linked lists aren't the only way an ordered set of data could be stored.  You're correct, Java array's are of course mutable, see my amended answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Producing a modified version of a list by allocating an array large enough to hold the modified version and copying over all of the unmodified elements is somewhat expensive, regardless of whether the modification is an append, an insert, a deletion, replacement, or anything else.  The cost is roughly comparable to that of producing an unmodified, but distinct, copy of the list.

If an object `Foo` wishes to maintain a list of elements in such a way that it can only be changed when `Foo` changes it, there are two common approaches it can use to do so:

1. It can use an "immutable list" type which guarantees that any instance which has ever been exposed to the outside world will forever hold the same sequence of objects.  The object `Foo` would be free to expose references to this list, since nobody would be able to alter it.  If `Foo` wants to e.g. add an item to its list, it would generate a new immutable list which contains all the items in the list, plus the new one, and start holding a reference to that instead of the old one.

   It can create a list object which is mutable, but is never exposed to the outside world.  If anyone needs to retrieve the sequence of items from the list, `Foo` would copy the list's contents into a new list with which the caller could use in any way it sees fit without affecting `Foo`s list..

If one uses approach #1, then every time `Foo` alters the list it must create a new "immutable list" instance, but `Foo` could answer a request for the list's contents without having to copy it.  If one uses approach #2, adding items to the list (and other modifications) will be cheaper, but answering a request for the list's contents will require copying the list.  Whether it's better to use approach #1 or approach #2 will depend upon how often the list is updated, versus how often the application will need a copy of it.

Answer (score 0):

Immutable objects can be shared between threads without synchronization.  Synchronization negatively affects scaling, and can potentially be more costly than the copy.

Comment: Mutable objects can just as well be shared for reading without synchronization.

Comment: @NiklasB.: If they're mutable, by definition they're subject to being written.  And then they can't be shared.

Comment: I meant that, if you never perform a write on a mutable data structure, you are using the data structure in a way that doesn't require synchronization. It all depends on the usage pattern.

Comment: @Niklas: If you are using a data structure in a way that forbids writing, that's an immutable data structure (nevermind that it may be built atop an implementation that allows mutation, the object in your program is quite immutable).

Comment: That's not the point. Immutable data structures forbid  mutation not by convention (as in, let's never write to it) but by lacking interface to modify the internal state. In particular, an immutable data structure can use the fact that it will never be mutated to make certain operations more efficient (like thread-safe iteration or prepending in the case of singly-linked lists). The question was specifically about appending to an array, though, which I consider strange.

Comment: @Niklas: A public interface is just a convention.  You can always poke new data on top of the object bypassing the intended interface.  In C++, that just requires some casting, in C# (or any .NET) `Marshal.Copy` will do it, in Java you might need a JNI call.  In the end though, immutability is an agreement between all users of an object not to ever write to it.  And language keywords can help catch unintentional violations of that agreement, even when they can't completely enforce it.